# Can Hive Supports Multiple Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hive, hadoop2

I have 2 hadoop cluster A and B. And i have hive setup on Cluster A. I am not able to access the data on cluster B from hive setup.
I am doing this to create the table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_table (id string)
LOCATION "hdfs://B/user/siddharth.a/test_sid";
```

I am getting the exception

```
message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: B
```

I am able to create the table.
Ex: The below command works.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_table (id string)
LOCATION "hdfs://ip_of_namenode_of_B/user/siddharth.a/test_sid";
```

if i use

```
dfs -ls hdfs://B/user/siddharth.a
```

this is working.The last command should fail as well.

Comment: What is your _"hive setup"_ > HiveServer2 + MetaStore? HiveServer2 with embedded Metastore? Legacy fat client `hive` + Metastore? Legacy fat client with embedded Metastore (tapping directly the underlying DB)?

Comment: Bottom line: does the process acting as Metastore (standalone or embedded) have in its CLASSPATH a `hdfs-site.xml` that defines cluster B?

Comment: @Samson Setup is legacy fat hive client + Metastore.

Comment: @SiddharthAgarwal have u got the answer? If yes please share